# Click to all different next pages into a loop until the last page with Watir gem

Tags: ruby, watir, ruby-watir

i have a problem in my ruby watir script.

I want to click through all next pages until the last page, and then puts some first name and last name. I know that the last "next" link is called with one more class "disabled" `stop = b.link(class: 'next-pagination page-link disabled')`.
I try to loop until this classes is reached `break if stop.exists?`

```
loop do
  link = b.link(class: 'next-pagination page-link') 
  name_array = b.divs(class: 'name-and-badge-container').map { |e| e.div(class:'name-container').link(class: 'name-link profile-link').text.split("\n") }
  puts name_array
  stop = b.link(class: 'next-pagination page-link disabled')
  break if stop.exists?
  link.click
end
```

I have this error :

> This code has slept for the duration of the default timeout waiting for an Element to exist. If the test is still passing, consider using Element#exists? instead of rescuing UnknownObjectException
>   /Users/vincentcheloudiakoff/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/watir-6.2.1/lib/watir/elements/element.rb:496:in `rescue in wait_for_exists': timed out after 30 seconds, waiting for #<Watir::Div: located: false; {:class=>"name-and-badge-container", :tag_name=>"div", :index=>13}> to be located (Watir::Exception::UnknownObjectException)
>       from /Users/vincentcheloudiakoff/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/watir-6.2.1/lib/watir/elements/element.rb:486:in`wait_for_exists'
>       from /Users/vincentcheloudiakoff/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/watir-6.2.1/lib/watir/elements/element.rb:487:in `wait_for_exists'
>       from /Users/vincentcheloudiakoff/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/watir-6.2.1/lib/watir/elements/element.rb:487:in`wait_for_exists'
>       from /Users/vincentcheloudiakoff/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/watir-6.2.1/lib/watir/elements/element.rb:639:in `element_call'
>       from /Users/vincentcheloudiakoff/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/watir-6.2.1/lib/watir/elements/element.rb:91:in`text'
>       from /Users/vincentcheloudiakoff/Travail/Automation/lib/linkedin.rb:24:in `block (2 levels) in start'
>       from /Users/vincentcheloudiakoff/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/watir-6.2.1/lib/watir/element_collection.rb:28:in`each'
>       from /Users/vincentcheloudiakoff/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/watir-6.2.1/lib/watir/element_collection.rb:28:in `each'
>       from /Users/vincentcheloudiakoff/Travail/Automation/lib/linkedin.rb:24:in`map'
>       from /Users/vincentcheloudiakoff/Travail/Automation/lib/linkedin.rb:24:in `block in start'
>       from /Users/vincentcheloudiakoff/Travail/Automation/lib/linkedin.rb:22:in`loop'
>       from /Users/vincentcheloudiakoff/Travail/Automation/lib/linkedin.rb:22:in `start'
>       from start.rb:3:in`'

It clicks on the next page, but does not find the next disabled button.

Comment: Can you provide the html part? , I might find better way to locate that link. The problem in your code is, it is not locating that element.

Comment: Yes, the html part is:

<a class="next-pagination page-link disabled" title="Suivant" data-page-number="2"><span class="pagination-text">Suivant</span></a>

This is the html part for the last "next" link

Comment: Why don't you locate that element using text? It would work.

Comment: Thank's a lot, it's work !

I just locate the span element like that

`stop = b.link(class: 'next-pagination page-link disabled').span(class: 'pagination-text')`

Comment: Hi, this is not the way I said, I said to locate using text directly. I have updated the answer below, you could check it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the text to locate that element

```
b.span(text: 'Suivant').click
```

You don't have to use parent link and then span like b.link().span() instead you can directly locate span the way I have explained.